# How to match book title and isbn with regex?

Tags: regex

Hi I am looking into writing a regular expression that will match the following

```
/book/The-title-of-the-book/0000000000/
```

where `The-title-of-the-book` is any alphanumeric character and a '-', `0000000000000` is the 10 or 13 digit isbn of the book, e.g. `/book/To-kill-a-mockingbird/0099419785/`.

can you suggest what pattern I may use to construct the regular expression

Comment: What do you want to match? Do you want to extract the title and the ISBN?

Answer (score 3):

```
/^\/book\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/(\d{10}|\d{13})\/$/
```

also you don't need `^` and `$` if you want to search text for this string

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/book/([a-zA-Z\d-]+)/(\d{10}|\d{13})/
```

Note that in some languages, the `/` is used to delimit the regex, in which case you'll need to escape the `/` in  it:

```
/\/book\/([a-zA-Z\d-]+)\/(\d{10}|\d{13})\//
```

Or use another delimiter, if possible.

The book will be captured in group 1, the isbn in group 2.

Comment: that'll match 10 to 13 digits, he needs either 10 or 13. isbn cannot be 11 or 12

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would not use regexes and just split the string on / the the last part is the ISBN and the second last the title.

I would refer to the comment

Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

from Jaime Zawinski

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\/book\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\/\d{10,13}\/$/
```

Not tested but I believe that should match what you want.

EDIT: This should make it so the ISBN is either 10 or 13 characters, not in-between.

```
/^\/book\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\/(\d{10}|\d{13})\/$/
```

Comment: See SilentGhost's earlier comment in my answer: *"that'll match 10 to 13 digits, he needs either 10 or 13. isbn cannot be 11 or 12"*.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you colud use:

```
^/book/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(\d{10,13})/$
```

Comment: See SilentGhost's earlier comment in my answer: "that'll match 10 to 13 digits, he needs either 10 or 13. isbn cannot be 11 or 12".

Answer (score 0):

```
/book/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{13})/
```

This does exactly what you want

- [a-zA-Z0-9-]+ : Tests for one or more alphanumeric characters
- ([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{13}) : Tests for 10 digits or 13 digits